# MARS MIPS Simulator Execute windows won't expand

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

Often when I switch to the "Execute" tab in MARS, the "text" and "data" windows are minimized and won't expand. Actually, "minimized" is the wrong word --- you can only see the top half of the title bar, so you can't even access the maximize button. Has anybody else seen this?  If so, do you know how to fix it?

I'm using MARS 4.5 on MacOS 10.15.

[image]

Comment: Having the same issue on MacOS 12.5.1. Did you figure it out?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 2):

Just unselect *Show Labels Window (symbolic table)* under Settings in the menu.

Here's what it looks like:

[image: here's a picture of what it looks like]

Answer (score 0):

Mine is MacOS 11.0.1. Solve this issue by open the .jar file through my java IDE.